# Solve linear equations system with only positive coefficients in solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, machine-learning

Can you advice the most efficient way to solve a system of linear equations where the solution vector has only positive coordinates?

$$A \times b  = c$$
$$\forall i,\, b_i > 0$$
Of course, in most cases exact solution does not exist, so the task is to minimize the error:
$$b =   \arg\min \|A\times b  - c\|_2$$

Comment: From the top of my head, I don't know about a specific algorithm for calculation positive solutions. But from a complexity perspective, it still does not seem that bad to use Gauss-Jordan to create the solution set and then using an optimized filter to search out positive solutions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm is probably what you need.